# Transcribe duplicate URL

Tags: ee2, transcribe

Google seems to be indexing multiple versions of our translated pages, namely with the language abbreviation and without.  The example below is a German translated page that is also showing without the abbreviation (also shows with other abbreviations es, fr etc.)

https://domain/de/library/guided-tests/can-high-und-can-low-diagnostik/

is correct with the abbreviation, and

https://domain/library/guided-tests/can-high-und-can-low-diagnostik/

Seem to be the same page but would ideally be redirected to a 404.
Because the site is primarily in English with established pages we chose to use the original English versions without an abbreviation.

How can we block pages without abbreviations or with the wrong abbreviation being indexed and/or a 404 redirect?

My initial thoughts was that if I could set a conditional checking if the entry was matched to the correct language abbreviation but I can’t figure if that’s possible or not.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If i am understanding you correctly this seems like a good use for the 'canonical' tag.  https://moz.com/learn/seo/canonicalization

Comment: Thanks AllinOne, I couldn't see the wood for the trees on this issue.  I'm using NSM Better meta so will implement the canonical tag.